# shift columns up or down by n rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, rows, shift

Let's suppose I have the following data.frame `df`:

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(a = rnorm(10), 
                b = rnorm(10), 
                c = rnorm(10), 
                d = rnorm(10))

> df
            a           b           c           d
1  -0.6264538  1.51178117  0.91897737  1.35867955
2   0.1836433  0.38984324  0.78213630 -0.10278773
3  -0.8356286 -0.62124058  0.07456498  0.38767161
4   1.5952808 -2.21469989 -1.98935170 -0.05380504
5   0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575 -1.37705956
6  -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874 -0.41499456
7   0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.15579551 -0.39428995
8   0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.47075238 -0.05931340
9   0.5757814  0.82122120 -0.47815006  1.10002537
10 -0.3053884  0.59390132  0.41794156  0.76317575
```

I desire to shift up (only) columns `b`, `c` and `d` by let's say 3 rows. Column `a` has to remain fixed and the rows with `NAs` removed.

Here my desired output for a shift of 3 rows:

```
> df_shift_3
            a           b           c           d
1  -0.6264538 -2.21469989 -1.98935170 -0.05380504 
2   0.1836433  1.12493092  0.61982575 -1.37705956
3  -0.8356286 -0.04493361 -0.05612874 -0.41499456
4   1.5952808 -0.01619026 -0.15579551 -0.39428995
5   0.3295078  0.94383621 -1.47075238 -0.05931340
6  -0.8204684  0.82122120 -0.47815006  1.10002537
7   0.4874291  0.59390132  0.41794156  0.76317575
```

How can I create a function that generalise this output for a `up` or `down` shift of `n` rows?

I tried to use the following function [https://rdrr.io/cran/useful/man/shift.column.html](http://function) but no success.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lead/lag` function from dplyr are helpful for this. `df %>% mutate_at(-1, ~lead(., 3)) %>% slice(1:(n()-3))`

And you can make it a function

```
shift_all_but_first <- function(data, N) data %>% mutate_at(-1, ~lead(., N)) %>% slice(1:(n()-N))

shift_all_but_first(df, 3)
```

Comment: thanks. how can I change the number of cols that has to remain fixed? let's say I want a and b to be fixed.

Comment: Just look at all the options that `mutate_at` has for choosing columns that you want to select.